# How could you retrieve a range of user highlighted cells in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

At the moment this is the function I'm using but I have no way of testing if it will work in the spreadsheet until I publish the application.

```
function readSelection() {
  //The commented lines aren't needed if the sheet is open already
  //var sheetid = "sheet id here";
  //var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid); 
  //SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(spreadsheet);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //sheet.setActiveSelection("B2:B22");
  var activerange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var activecells = activerange.getValues();

  return activecells;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean highlighted == selected

The result depends on whether the cells are contiguous or not (non contiguous cell selection is available in the new spreadsheets features http://googleblog.blogspot.co.nz/2013/12/new-google-sheets-faster-more-powerful.html

For contiguous cells selected your code returns the values of the selection as an array, for non-contiguous cells your code will return the an array with the single value of the LAST selected item.

I suggest that this is a bug in the implementation of the new spreadsheet. If it is important to you, I suggest you raise an issue. For the old spreadsheets, you can only select contiguous cells (eg B2:B22) so it will work as you expect.

The easiest way to answer this Q is to run the code you have written! You don't have to publish anything just run the code in the script editor of the spreadsheet you are examining
and look at the log.

```
 function readSelection() {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var activerange = sheet.getActiveRange();

  var activecells = activerange.getValues();
Logger.log(activecells)
  return 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this at the moment or to obtain the selected ranges from a script.
A request is pending and you can support it here : https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4056
by adding a star to the request.

If/when this function is implemented your code would look as follows:

```
 function readSelection() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var activeranges = sheet.getSelectedRanges();
  var activecells = [] ;'

  for (var ar in activeranges) 
     activecells = activecells.concat(activeranges[ar].getValues()) ; 

  Logger.log(activecells)
  return ;
  }
```

note that selected ranges may overlap, so some cell contents could be added twice.